# Change URL of page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, url

Here is the deal: I have a login form where the user logs in. If validation passes, they are redirected to

```
example.com/members/landing
```

How can I change this into only `example.com/landing`. Is there any way to change the url shown to the user on browser,  while in the back, the form_open has different methods to call

e.g: as stated above, in form the code is

```
<?php echo form_open(members/landing); ?>
```

but the browser must display landing or anything....

Comment: Can't you just use the [routes config](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) and define your `site.com/anything` to be routed to `members/landing` internally?

Answer (score 1):

In config/routes.php:

```
$route['landing'] = '/members/landing';
```

What this does is send any request to `example.com/landing` to the  `example.com/members/landing` controller. So then your form:

```
<?php echo form_open('/landing'); ?>
```

should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using codeigniter, edit your routes.php and change the default Controller; or if you only need to display custom URL, you can use .htaccess file.